# Automated Testing

Tags: .net, testing

Does anyone know of a free or trial version to test an .net web site?  It must go to a url with parameters (which will generate an excel file), then the open/save dialog pops up, and either open then save it, or just save it.  It will then loop and go onto the next url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd write a simple AutoIT script to do this - http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/

It's easy and fast to learn, and compiles to .exe, so no special environment is required to run it.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps can http://watin.org/ help?

Answer (score 1):

Check out TestComplete by SmartBear. Has scripted and keyword driven testing for web apps and works with .net including with many rich Web technologies, such as, HTML5, Flash and Flex.

http://smartbear.com/products/qa-tools/automated-testing-tools/?_ga=1.73287379.1362197236.1363803531

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you want any specifications about .net web application but i can suggest [selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/).

Comment: "Saving an excel file" can you explain more please?

Comment: A message box pops up from a webpage asking you to save or open the file from firefox

Comment: This is not about automated test tool. You can make it with tools or JavaScript libraries like [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) . And yes selenium can click any button to pop up, can select any file if given path is correct, can click a button to save it etc.. If you wrote any code with selenium, post it.

Comment: How do i get selenium to save this file and rename it: http://selenium.googlecode.com/files/selenium-dotnet-2.0b3.zip

Comment: Dude I meant if you wrote any code about selenium post here maybe we can figure out whats wrong with it.

Comment: Why would I write code since I don't think Selenium has the power to save and rename a file from the web. It can open the link to the download but then it will hang.

Answer (score 0):

If all you've got is a list of URLs, and you want to grab the contents of each and save them, you don't really need a full-blown automated testing tool - create an [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) for each one, then get the response and call [GetResponseStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.getresponsestream.aspx) on it. Write that stream to a file and you're done.

If you want to open the file you've just saved in Excel, you can call [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8zac0ca.aspx) with the path to the .XLS file and UseShellExecute=true. That will open the file in Excel, or whatever program is set as the default file association.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with QA Agent(http://qaagent.com/). It is 100% free and it is really easy to develop automated tests. QA Agent is web based IDE and it is really easy to start developing your tests with it and also to automated some daily based tasks.